# Modify StylusPoints of an InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

How can I modify the 'X' and 'Y' coordinates of  `INKCanvas1.Strokes[0].StylusPoints[0].X`?

I tried it out the whole day, I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand the problem; you can easily loop through all the strokes and access the X and Y value. Here is a piece of example code that changes all strokes into lines:

```
for(int i=0;i<INKCanvas1.Strokes.Count;i++)
{
   for(int j=0;j<INKCanvas1.Strokes[i].StylusPoints.Count;j++)
   {
      // since StylusPoint[j] is returning a reference to
      // a struct you need to set it to a variable
      var y = INKCanvas1.Strokes[i].StylusPoint[j].Y;

      //Set it to x=200 and y= stroke y value
      INKCanvas1.Strokes[i].StylusPoint[j] =  new StylusPoint(200,y)


   }
}
```

For more info read the documentation of [StylusPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.styluspoint.aspx) and [StylusPointCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.styluspointcollection.aspx).